@node_modules keeps showing in Visual Studio Code auto import and suggesions in Nextjs 15
When I try to import a component or function from a dependency vscode displays @node_modules before the path, for example if I tried to import toast from sonner vscode is gonna import it like this:
import { toast } from "@node_modules/sonner/dist"

instead of:
import { toast } from "sonner"

here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

This happens with all dependencies not only sonner
I made sure typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier is set to "shortest" but I still have the same problem
I only started experiencing this issue when I started using nextjs 15, it didn't happen in nextjs 14 or any other framework or language.
